# Trying to get mysql like function to work with function

Tags: mysql, concatenation, sql-like

The following statement works fine:

```
mysql> select concat('/Parent/Child/',date_format(subdate(current_date,1),'%Y/%m/%d'));
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat('/Parent/Child/',date_format(subdate(current_date,1),'%Y/%m/%d')) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| /Parent/Child/2017/06/14                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but for some reason I can't do a like comparison with this information. What am I missing here?

I keep getting an empty set which I know is incorrect.

Can someone provide me the correct 'where  like ' syntax?

Comment: Where are using Like in this? Share the code which is not working and explain how it is not working and how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually as easy as concatinating % to before and after initial concat.